# Show all types not only send in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a question. I have table 'codes' with fields

id, baseName, code, send

id - Identifier of record
baseName - Identifier of category
code - not important field
send - info does this code was send or not

Now i want to display for all of category how many codes was send.

I wrote this query

```
SELECT codes.baseName, Count(codes.code) FROM codes WHERE codes.send =  '1' GROUP BY codes.baseName
```

But it gives me count from only baseName from were code was send.

For example

If i have 5 category and send=1 will be in only 3 category it count and MySQL shows me only 3 category but i want to recieve All 5 category but where Count(codes.code) = 0 i  want also saw it with 0.

My Result

```
baseName | Count(codes.code)
    2             14
    3             12
    5             15
```

Result which i want to have

```
baseName | Count(codes.code)
    1              0
    2             14
    3             12
    4              0
    5             15
```

Please give me an advice how to upgrade my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT codes.baseName, sum(case when codes.send = '1' then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM codes
GROUP BY codes.baseName
```